# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null on line 15

Tags: javascript, php

Notice: Undefined index: data on line 15

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null on line 15
I Am new to javascript database connections and can't find why I am getting this error.

If more information is needed to find a solution just say what is missing because its a 200+ line code

Edit(`<td class="center-blocks"><label id="labelname"><?php echo $FieldData["NoClaim"]; ?></label></td>`) this is also getting the same Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "init.php";
$RecordID = $_SESSION["RecordId"];
$findrecords = array(
    "query" => array(
        array(
            "RecordId" => $RecordID
        )
    )
);

$result = $fm6->findRecords($findrecords);
$RecordId = $result["result"]["response"];
$FieldData = $result ["result"]["response"]["data"][0]["fieldData"]; Line 15

include 'Header.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: it means that somewhere between `$result ["result"]["response"]["data"]` and `$result ["result"]["response"]["data"][0]["fieldData"]` the index does not exist. Easy way to go about finding this out is to find out what the data structure looks like is to do a `var_dump` after line 13. also check the usage of [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting "data" in response object.
$result ["result"]["response"]["data"];

```
try this
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result ["result"]["response"]["data"]);
    exit;
```